# Java generics void/Void types

Tags: java, void, return-type

I am implementing a `ResponseHandler` for the apache HttpClient package, like so:

```
new ResponseHandler<int>() {
    public int handleResponse(...) {
        // ... code ...
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but I'd like for the `handleResponse` function to return nothing, i.e. `void`. Is this possible? The following does not compile, since `void` is not a valid Java type:

```
new ResponseHandler<void>() {
        public void handleResponse(...) {
            // ... code ...
        }
}
```

I suppose I could replace `void` with `Void` to return a `Void` object, but that's not really what I want. **Question**: is it possible to organize this callback situation in such a way that I can return `void` from `handleResponse`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Generics only handles object classes.  void and primitive types are not supported by Generics and you cannot use these as a parameterized type.  You have to use Void instead.

Can you say why you don't want to use `Void`?

Comment: i'd just prefer not to have to include a `return` statement in a function where I'm not returning anything, for cleanliness mostly.

Comment: You could create an abstract wrapper which call you `void` method and returns `null` to hide this ugliness.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that "any problem in computer science can be solved by adding a layer of indirection"

Comment: @TravisWebb Looking at your specific need, just don't use generics at all and return `Object` type if it'll work

Answer (score 111):

The `Void` type was created for this exact situation: to create a method with a generic return type where a subtype can be "void". `Void` was designed in such a way that no objects of that type can possibly be created. Thus a method of type `Void` will always return `null` (or complete abnormally), which is as close to nothing as you are going to get. You do have to put `return null` in the method, but this should only be a minor inconvenience.

In short: Do use `Void`.

Comment: Arrgh - the pain of generics the issue is if lets say you define a return type of "Void" you must put in a "return(null);" the main reason to declare the return type of void is so you don't have to have a return statement, and can use an existing "void" method :)  Part of the issue with Java Generics is the conflation of run-time type checking with the need for compile time code generation and "bookeeping" assistance.  One needs "macros" and "templates" that offer convenience in writing code on the *language* side.

Comment: +1 To clarify, Void has been around since JDK1.1.  It was originally created for use with Reflection but has a similar role in generics.

Comment: @ILMTitan Could you please give any references to the documentation about "return null" statement in methods that defined to return Void?

Comment: @andriy-simonov Methods with a return type of `void` do not have to return a value. Methods with a return type of `Object` or any subclass, such as `Void` do have to return a value (or not complete normally). The only value that can be assigned to `Void`, and therefor returned from a `Void` method, is `null`.

Answer (score 16):

When you need to return `java.lang.Void`, just return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have primitives in generics so that `int` is actually an `Integer`. The object `Void` is analogous with the keyword `void` for generics.

Comment: `void` is not a primitive, it's merely a java keyword. It has no "type"

Comment: and it surely is not synonymous! `void` (lowercase) - keyword, nothing returned; `Void` (uppercase) - an (uninstantiable) **class**, instance of that class being returned (can only be `null` since uninstantiable)

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger analogous any better for you ?

Answer (score 0):

This java.lang.Void implementation in Java kind of speaks for itself. Also, I wrote an article that ties this into generics. It took a bit of thought before I started understanding this: http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/D00006.php. Notice TYPE = Class.getPrimitiveClass("void");

package java.lang;

```
public final class Void {

    public static final Class<Void> TYPE = Class.getPrimitiveClass("void");

    private Void() {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Alas it's not possible.** You can set the code to return `Void` as you say, however you can never instanciate a `Void` so you can't actually write a function which conforms to this specification.

Think of it as: The generic function says "this function returns something, of type X", and you can specify X but you can't change the sentence to "this function returns nothing". (I'm not sure if I agree with these semantics, but that's the way they are.)

In this case, what I always do, is just make the function return type `Object`, and in fact always return `null`.

Comment: Because with a return type of Object the compiler cannot guarantee that only null is returned. Expanding on Thomas' answer, try these:    `static Void v() { return null; } `    `static Void n() { return "NotAllowed"; } `    `static Object o() { return "Allowed"; } `

Comment: Yeah, I know, this is ancient history at this point, but as I recently ended up here, wanted to call out that this answer is actually incorrect.  You can return the Void type.  It is true that you can't have an instantiated object of this type, but since all object types in Java are nullable, you can return null.  Essentially, what you are doing with the Object type is what you should be doing with the Void type.  The Void type correctly expresses that only null will ever be returned.