# Why Reactor Mono<Void> is recognized as an empty Mono?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

Here is the piece of code

```
@Test
public void test_mono_void_mono_empty() {
    Mono.just("DATA")
        .flatMap(s -> Mono.just(s.concat("-")
                                 .concat(s))
                          .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                          .then())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("EMPTY")
                           .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                           .then())
        .block();
}
```

that gives the following result to the console:

```
DATA-DATA
EMPTY
```

That means that the chain in the first `flatMap` was recognized as an empty one.

On the other hand Reactor has the following class [MonoEmpty](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoEmpty.java) that is returned by a `Mono.empty()` [method](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.java). On top of that, the method says the following:

```
/**
 * Create a {@link Mono} that completes without emitting any item.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/empty.svg" alt="">
 * <p>
 * @param <T> the reified {@link Subscriber} type
 *
 * @return a completed {@link Mono}
 */
public static <T> Mono<T> empty() {
    return MonoEmpty.instance();
}
```

*without emitting any item* - but I emitted  `Void` typed object with `then()` method.

What is the explanation of that?

Comment: `s.concat("-").concat(s)` should probably be written as `s + "-" + s`

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica do not see any difference

Comment: `+` can be optimized by the compiler whereas with `concat()` you have no such guarantee: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47626/5515060

Comment: I meant no difference in the scope of the question. How is it related to the topic?

Comment: It is not, but does it have to be? I just simply proposed an improvement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, the answer is in the [official java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Void.html) that says `The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void`.

That means that its main idea is simply to represent the void return type as a class and contain a `Class<Void>` public value. That's it. Besides, it's not instantiable as the constructor is private. All of that subsequently means that the only value we can assign to a `Void` variable is `null` what always is recognized as `empty Mono`.

helpful discussion:
[Java generics void/Void types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568409/java-generics-void-void-types)

Comment: "the only value we can assign to a Void variable is null what always is recognized as empty Mono" - careful with that; it may be subtly missing what's happening here. You can't propagate null through a reactive stream at all, but you *can* simply propagate nothing at all before a completion signal (which a `Mono<Void>` implies.)

Answer (score 11):

A given `Mono` can publish either nothing, or a single value before sending a completion signal. (It can't publish `null` - the reactive spec forbids it.) The generic type of the `Mono` denotes the type of the object that *might* be emitted - but there's no guarantee it *will* be emitted.

A `Mono<Foo>` for example can emit just a completion signal, or an instance of `Foo` and then a completion signal.

There's two common scenarios where a value may not be published - the first is if a value may or may not exist (such as searching for an item in a database or collection). In that case, you'd still use a `Mono<SomeType>`, and it may or may not emit a `SomeType` instance. The second scenario is if a value will definitely *never* be published (often used when you just need notification that a task has completed), and for that, by convention, `Mono<Void>` is always used. `then()`, in your above example, falls into the second case.

The reason that `Mono<Void>` is a special case is that, as you point out, `Void` is a class that can never be instantiated by design. There's therefore no such thing as an instance of `Void`, which means the `Mono` can never emit a value before its completion signal.

The logical conclusion therefore is that a publisher of type `Mono<Void>` can never emit a value, only a completion signal - and so it is used as such.