# Optional generic type argument

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I want to declare a generic class that will work on triplets - `key`, `value` and `metadata`.

The `key` and `value` fields are mandatory but the `metadata` field is optional.

```
class Triplet<K,V,M>{
    K key;
    V value;
    M metadata;
    //setters and getters
}
```

While using the above class I have to initialize it like below -

```
Triplet<Integer, String, String> t1 = new Triplet<>();
// Setters
```

But for some use cases `metadata` is optional. So when I use `null` as the 3rd type argument, the compiler gives an error -

```
Triplet<Integer, String, null> t2 = new Triplet<>();
```

How should I correctly instantiate a parameterized type that works for multiple types, where one of the type arguments specified at the use-site is optional?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568409/java-generics-void-void-types

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Void` e.g.

```
Triplet<Integer, String, Void> t2 = new Triplet<>();
```

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that if you determine that the third parameter is not present (as intended by using `null`), then it's no longer a triplet, but a pair. Just keep things simple and use a `Pair` class instead.

Answer (score 5):

Java does not support "optional" or gradual typing. You can try creating a subclass that defaults metadata to `null`, i.e. `NoMetadataTriple<K,V>`, or give `Void` for M instead as mentioned in the other answer.

The [`Void`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) "type" cannot be instantiated. It's basically `void` (the output parameter) as a `Class`.